# change name of class based on the content of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming this structure:

```
<div class="item price-class">
  <div class="product-box">
  <h2 class="price">340</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item price-class">
  <div class="product-box">
  <h2 class="price">450</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item price-class">
  <div class="product-box">
  <h2 class="price">870</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

how can I change the name .price-class into let's say .340-price, .450-price, .870-price (and be able to apply it to multiple items dynamicaly?

Comment: Create the classes .340 .450 and .870 and append them when needed?

Comment: That would be a good solution, but like I said, I need this to happen dynamically. There will be many items with many different prices and the price of each item should be added as a class name to the main item container.

Comment: Please post [**your code**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) you are currently attempting to do this with so we can have a look and see why it is not working. In addition, adding a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) (or similar) that demonstrates the issue also helps.

Comment: why would you want to do that? what's the purpose of creating those new classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/9T6CS/)**

```
$('.price').each(function(){

    $(this).parents('.price-class').removeClass('price-class').addClass($(this).html()+'-price');
});
```

You need to use **[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)** and **[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that:

```
$('.price-class').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this
        .removeClass('price-class')
        .addClass($this.find('.price').text() + '-price');
});
```

Documentation:

[addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

[removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

[each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$("div.item").each(function() {
    var element = $(this).find(".price");
    var price = element.text();
    element.removeClass("price");
    element.addClass(price + "-price");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".price-class").each(function(){
        price = $(this).text();
        $(this).removeClass("price-class").addClass(price+"-class");
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yvAW/

```
$(".item .product-box .price").each(function(ind, el) {
    var txt = $(el).text();
    $(el).closest(".item").addClass(txt + "-price");
});
```